# Why is Content Provider without permissions and with exported=true accessible to any app?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-permissions

Here is a test I ran to understand Android Content Provider permissions:

App *ProviderApp* manifest:

```
<provider
    android:authorities="com.mycompany.myProviderApp"
    android:name="com.mycompany.myProviderApp.ContentProviderForMyOtherApps"
    android:exported="true"/>
```

I also implemented a dummy `ContentProvider` (`ContentProviderForMyOtherApps`) with a basic `query` method returning a string in *ProviderApp*:

```
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
    String[] cols = {"column1"};
    MatrixCursor cursor = new MatrixCursor(cols);
    MatrixCursor.RowBuilder builder = cursor.newRow();
    builder.add("HELLO!");
    return cursor;
}
```

---

App *ClientApp* code:

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://com.mycompany.myProviderApp"),null,null,null,null);
cursor.moveToFirst();
Log.d(TAG, cursor.getString(0)); // output: HELLO!
```

---

Okay, so everything is working fine, *ClientApp* accesses the provider successfully.

But my understanding of the documentation, based on the excerpts below, is that *ClientApp* should have been **denied** access to the provider, because:

- *ProviderApp* manifest has no `android:readPermission` inside the `provider` (e.g. `com.mycompany.myProviderApp.READ`)
- *ClientApp* manifest has no matching `uses-permission` (e.g. `com.mycompany.myProviderApp.READ`)

Documentation excerpts:

> If a provider's application doesn't specify any permissions, then **other applications have no access to the provider's data.**

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html#Permissions

> android:exported
>
> Whether the content provider is available for other applications to
>   use: true: The provider is available to other applications. Any
>   application can use the provider's content URI to access it, **subject
>   to the permissions specified for the provider.**

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/provider-element.html

**Why is this code (provider and client declaring NO permissions) actually working?**

(What have I missed in the documentation?)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The documentation has a bug. This:

> If a provider's application doesn't specify any permissions, then other applications have no access to the provider's data.

should read as:

> If a provider's application doesn't specify any permissions, then other applications' access to the provider's data is determined solely by the `android:exported` value (`true` grants unlimited access to all applications; `false` blocks access by other applications) and `android:grantUriPermissions` value (which gets complicated).

IMHO, that whole section needs to be rewritten. But, with respect to your test, an exported permission-less provider is wide open, with any app being able to read and write with impunity.

Comment: I added write and read permissions ("android:writePermission="my.package.test.READ"") but I still have full access when exported is set to true.